# i cant install anyting in my ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

```
sujith@sujith:~$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
[sudo] password for sujith: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gdebi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 was **not** a LTS release; thus had a life of 9 months. If you want/need a longer life for your Ubuntu, please use LTS releases (supported for 5 years).  17.04 was released in 2017-April (why its 17.04) + 9 months = 2018-Jan-13 EOL date.   Ubuntu releases are easy to know EOL as just add 5 to year for LTS *16.04+5y=2021.04*, or add 9  to month number *17.04+9m=18.01*

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 17.04 has reached end of life, as you can see here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases. This means it receives no further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades. You should upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version (preferably wait for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to be released - it's on April 26th).